# Import/Export Tool not working in 1.9.2

Tags: import, export, ce-1.9.2.0

Since upgrading to 1.9.2 my import/export tool no longer works.  For exports I get a white screen and the imports stop with the please wait processing message.

Comment: Could you please turn of error logging and post your system.log and exception.log, this should help debug the issue.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue.  There was a memory limit problem on the server side.